# List specific VM details of azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I need to list `Name, IpAddress, ServiceName and InstanceStatus` for all azure vm under my subscription ID. Is there any way out so that I can save all these details into some text file or display it on screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you have Azure powershell installed in your machine, its very easy.
Run this command if you want to see the result on your monitor-

```
Get-AzureVM | Format-List Name, IpAddress, ServiceName, InstanceStatus
```

If you want to save this detail in text file use this-

```
Get-AzureVM | Format-List Name, IpAddress, ServiceName, InstanceStatus > c:\Myfolder\VMDetails.txt
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Great Work Mr @Aatif.